# Ideas to change the price value using javascript on Trading View Order

Tags: javascript, sendkeys, trading, tradingview-api

I am working on order automation for Trading View.
Although I have been able to make some progress, changing the price for limit orders (as well as the quantity, any number) has been a challenge. I am able to change the value on the input but it doesn't really get updated in the app model (hence the buy button never reflects the change).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the view of the value is not bidirectional connected to the hidden input field. Seems like the trading app is using some reactive framework, they usually integrate some UI components library, and those libraries hide the real input field in behind the beautiful mask of the ux oriented view on the front side.

Here you have 2 options

1. Try to set the value of hidden input field in behind the component and try to send the request to see if the new value is fetched, no matter if its visible on front or no
2. I think more user friendly option, to trigger the events on the HTML elements, this will require more research from your side to learn how to trigger events and check the results of those events step by steps. If you already know it then it will be fast.
   For Example:

```js
// Let's say pure js

// Keep in mind, id of element, not a hidden input field.
const dropdown = document.getElementById('idOfHTMLElement');
dropdown.click(); // After click the options of the dropdown should appear

const options = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('classNameOfDropDownOption'));
const desiredOption = options.find((option) => option.someConditionLikePriceOrSmthElse: boolean);

desiredOption.click();

// Something like this, not accurate code, please test and correct if you will use this
```

Comment: thank you for your response. you are right, the app seems to be developed with react and I can't trigger the right events to force the update of the model. I tried to update the html elements but still the same result, no update. thanks again

Comment: as I mentioned, dont manually update the html element, instead of them emulate the events such as mousemove, mosuenter click etc... its very similar to writin automated tests on js components.

First just do what you would do manualy, then emulate the same using js events